# Git equivalent of "hg id"?

Tags: git, version-control, mercurial, dvcs

Does Git have any command equivalent to Mercurial's "hg id"? I.e. a command that prints the parent commit's hash and a plus sign if there are changes in the working directory?

Comment: `git rev-parse HEAD` can report the hash.

Comment: Thanks everyone for the answers. I was looking for a quick equivalent, to let me know the hash of the parent commit and if the working directory has been modified compared to this. I guess the answer is that I can get that information by combining other commands.

Comment: @DCoder Should add that as an answer.

Answer (score 14):

This command is equivalent to `hg id --id`:

`git describe --abbrev=12 --always --dirty=+`

Answer (score 4):

```
git log -1 HEAD^
```

will show you the whole commit including the SHA-1

If it's a merge, you can see the second parent's commit info with

```
git log -1 HEAD^2
```

If you have an octopus merge with more than 2 parents you can put any number in the tree-ish spec:

```
git log -1 HEAD^5
```

... to see the 5th parent's commit info

the `-1` just limits the log output to one commit. You don't want the lineage of that commit reported.

Comment: The question is about a parent of the working dir (the hg way of thinking), so it is asking for the HEAD itself (and its diff wrt working dir, of course).

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there's a command *exactly* like that, but you can use:

```
git status --porcelain
```

which outputs a machine-readable listing of changed files in the repository. You can look for anything in the first column that is not `?` to indicate a changed file.

Comment: This doesn't return an id.
I got as return: 

    "?? workdir/"

Answer (score 0):

`git status` would show the changes in the working directory, and the branch info.

I guess `git log` can be used to see the last few commits.

Answer (score 0):

`git ls-remote REPOSITORY BRANCH` will show the hash of the head of a given branch.

https://git-scm.com/docs/git-ls-remote.html